# How to view users profile page in Trac?

Tags: profile, trac

How can I view user profile pages in Trac? I have Account Manager Plugin and User Manager Plugin already installed but I can only see user profiles in admin pages and only for user who is logged in with TRAC_ADMIN permission.

What I need is to see our users profile page with their basic information such as email address, image and full name.

If I've missed any needed information let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Basis information, email and full name are always viewable and changeable from the Preferences page of stock Trac for the logged-in user.

Nudge the maintainer of UserManagerPlugin, if you need the image too, since AccountManager doesn't know anything about the content added by UserManager.

Since both plugins address the needs of **admin users**, not regular ones, your requirement for profiles being visible to other users is definitely a fundamental enhancement request.

As a side-note: A sane implementation will even require at least one additional permission, something like 'USER_VIEW' or similar. Today everything is still dedicated to 'TRAC_ADMIN' in UserManager. AccountManager has done a little bit better in this respect since it's earlier days, because there are already multiple permission 'ACCTMGR_CONFIG_ADMIN', 'ACCTMGR_USER_ADMIN' and 'ACCTMGR_ADMIN'. I guess, going beyond on this road is just a matter of consequence.?

Please keep me updated, how it goes with UserManager, so I could escalate the case, if this plugin is currently unmaintained, as the commit history suggests.

Comment: I need to see other users profiles. It's the basic reason for having the profile.

Comment: I created a ticket for adding public profile to UserManagerPlugin at [link](https://trac-hacks.org/ticket/9506)

Comment: You may find my recent addition to my initial answer helpful as well. Please consider accepting it as the answer you took to go on, like this could be easier to spot for others following with similar issues. Thanks for taking care.

Comment: @MehdiSadeqi I've had the chance to talk to the author of UserManagerPlugin, Catalin Balan lately. While he couldn't promise any action because of other current projects, I've got permission to co-maintain. Follow-up on your ticket with detailed requirements and tracking it's state will be the best way to encourage me, that this should be done. :-)